# Python: Generating random data with bounds

Tags: python, optimization

I'm trying to generate random data with lower and upper bounds. I haven't found another way to do define the bounds than lists.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import qmc

sampler = qmc.LatinHypercube(d=4)

u_bounds = [2, 10, 10, 2]
l_bounds = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
data = sampler.lhs_method(100)*(u_bounds-(l_bounds)) + (l_bounds)
```

This code produces this error

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'`

Any ideas? S.O.S

Comment: What do you think `(u_bounds-(l_bounds))` means?

Comment: What are `u_bounds` and `l_bounds` supposed to be for? Are you generating one for each one of them?

Comment: Are you trying to do something like `[sampler.lhs_method(100) * (j-i) + i for i,j in zip(l_bounds, u_bounds)]`?

Comment: Use Numpy arrays or a loop (eg. `u_bounds = np.array([2, 10, 10, 2], dtype=np.float64)`)

Comment: Thanks @JérômeRichard, Numpy arrays made it work

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you tried to subbstract two list:

```
data = sampler.lhs_method(100)*(u_bounds-(l_bounds)) + (l_bounds)
```

is equal to:

```
data = sampler.lhs_method(100)*([2, 10, 10, 2] - [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
) + [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
```

So your error is normal!

I don't really understand what you tried, but if you want to generate random value between two number, try to use:

```
nb = random.randint(0, 9)
```